# Adding Database Connections in JSP page in Eclipse

Tags: java, html, database, jsp, jdbc

I'm trying to add Database connections to my JSP page. I've added this code in a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse and have tried to run it, but the below code only displays the heading, throwing an error saying "Class Not Found Exception: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver".

To check if there is something wrong with the code I implemented it on a separate java file and it runs successfully there displaying the table values.

Do I need to add a specific jar file? I've added the jtds-1.2.5.jar but still no change.

```
<body>
<h3>Database Connections</h3>
<%
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<server-name>:<port-number>/<database-name>", "<user>", "<password>");
        String sql = "Select * from <table-name>";
        Statement stmt = null;
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = null;
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
%>
<table>
    <%
        while (rs.next()) {
    %>
    <tr>
        <td><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>
    </tr>
    <%
        }
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    %>
</table>
```

My java File

```
Class.forName( "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" );

        Conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<server-name>:<port-number>/<database-name>", "<user>", "<password>");

        String sql="SELECT * FROM <table_name>";


        Statement stmt = Conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql );

        while ( rs.next() ) {

            String id = rs.getString(1);
                    System.out.println("ID:  "+id);
        } // while  
    } 
    catch ( Exception e ) {
        System.err.println( "Error: " + e.getMessage() );
        e.printStackTrace();

        System.exit( -2 );
    } // try-catch
```

Comment: why don't you want to make it more fixable ? create a class called DB and then import the class in JSP .
also you can make more method without wasting your time

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll try that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add te driver library jtds-1.2.5.jar either to tomcat/libs/ or to your webapps WEB-INF/lib directory.

Restart tomcat after you put the file in.

**Notes**

- Class.forName () is no longer needed since jdbc 4.0
- jsp scriplets are very outdated. Check out jstl and so on

Comment: Thanks for all the tips! I'll change my code accordingly

Comment: Once you find an answer that fixes your issue be sure to accept it. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! I followed all your tips and now its working :)

Answer (score 0):

add the jtds-1.2.5.jar to WEB-INF/lib and redeploy your project

AlSO:
i would advice you to learn JPA -**java-persistence-api**  instead of writing so many sql queries and creating many instance of connection class